# How to copy data from 1 tab to another in excel as TEXT with a macro

Tags: vba, excel

The code I have to copy data from 1 tab to another works as I'd expect it to BUT I actually want it to copy the data as text (visual cell contents) as opposed to copying the formulas over, the code I have is:

```
Sub sbCopyRangeToAnotherSheet()

Sheets("UK").Range("A5:AJ110").Copy
Destination:=Sheets("Template").Range("A5")

Sheets("UK").Range("A5:AJ110").Copy

Sheets("Template").Activate

Range("A5").Select

ActiveSheet.Paste

Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Is there any way to easily manipulate this code so it will do what I want it to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will transfer the [Range.Value property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195193.aspx). You can also pass across the [Range.Value2 property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193553.aspx) which is a raw version of the value.

```
Sub sbCopyRangeToAnotherSheet()
    With Sheets("UK").Range("A5:AJ110")
        Sheets("Template").Range("A5").Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count) = .Value
    End With
End Sub
```

There is also the [Range.Text property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840217.aspx) but this should be reserved for special cases where value or value2 is insufficient. The .Text property is read-only and can be passed across from individual cell to individual cell.

Saving the Template worksheet to a new workbook is a small matter of copying it with no destination. This results in a copy of the single Template worksheet being created in a new workbook which also becomes the ActiveWorkbook.

```
Sub sbSaveAnotherSheet()
    Dim fp As String, fn As String

    fp = Environ("USERPROFILE") & Chr(92) & "Documents"  '<~~user's Documents folder
    fn = "My_New_Workbook"
    With Sheets("Template")
        'with no destination given, the following code line copies
        'the Template worksheet to a new workbook which becomes the ActiveWorkbook
        .Copy
        'Save this new workbook as a .XLSX
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=fp & Chr(92) & fn, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
    End With
End Sub
```

No file extension is provided in the [Workbook.SaveAs method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841185.aspx). This will be supplied by the **FileFormat** parameter (see [xlFileFormat Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff198017.aspx)). If omitted, the file format will be that which is stated in Excel Options ► Save ► Save File in this Format.

Comment: as a bonus task, would you know know to then save this "Template" tab as an excel file?...
I have looked into this and I have code that does exactly what I want is here, I just dont know how to combine them:
    Sub Sample()

        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Template").Copy

        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "Desktop", FileFormat:=51

    End Sub

Comment: I've supplied some framework for saving the Template worksheet above.

Comment: Thank you jeeped, but does this code both copy the data to the template and then save the template or would I need 2 buttons to work both of these macros? (In the UK tab it would be useful to have 1 button that works both of these macros)

Comment: Just combine them. With the two sitting in a code page one on top of the other, remove `End Sub` from the first and remove `Sub sbSaveAnotherSheet()` from the second.